# HP Fortify External Entity Injection Web API XPathDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, fortify, xpathdocument

HP Fortify has shown that some boiler plate code for .NET Web API 2 could be susceptible to External entity injection with xml.

the code in question looks like this

```
if (documentPath == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("documentPath");
        }

        XPathDocument xpath = new XPathDocument(documentPath);  // badness here
        _documentNavigator = xpath.CreateNavigator();
```

Can anyone shed some like on how to resolve this??

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: This depends on the context of your code, which Fortify doesn't interpret. If `documentPath` comes from user input then you are vulnerable, however if you validate and sanitize the `documentPath` and handle this in code where you ensure only the valid files are allowed - then it can be marked as a false positive.